# C# SQL Add parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I tried to return a row by executing following SQL query in C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string selectquery = "SELECT TOP (1) [ZVNr] ZVNR_TABLE WHERE [ZVNr] = @zvnr order by [ZVNr] DESC";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zvnr", "20170530-01");
cmd.CommandText = selectquery;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

try
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(recordsAffected != -1)
    {
         return 0;
    }
    else
    {                   
         return 1;
    }
```

And the "ZVNR_TABLE" looks like this:

```
ZVNR | varchar (50)

20170530-01
```

The result is always --> recordsAffected = -1

Although when I'm executing the same SQL query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it works.

Comment: You're using a `SELECT` statement in your code and use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` which is for `INSERT` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `SELECT` statement in your code with `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` which is used for `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements.
You have to use a [SQLDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) (more than 1 row and(!) column) or Scalar (1 row/1col = one "item").

[MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx) for `SQLDataReader`:

```
//SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM tbl; 
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                reader.GetString(1));
    }
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
}
reader.Close();
```

[MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ExecuteScalar`:

```
//SELECT COUNT(*) FROM region; or any other single value SELECT statement
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //cast the type as needed
```

If you want the affected count after you change items in your database, you can get it by using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` which returns that count:

[MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
//INSERT INTO tbl (...) VALUES (...) or any other non-query statement
int rowsAffected = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

Comment: Execute scalar returns the column requested not the affected rows. 

int affectedCount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 

ZVNr from the example is a string so your query will definitely error out.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are Selecting the data from the datatable not inserting or updating the records that's why recordsAffected is always -1

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is used for `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements and returns the number of rows affected.
If you want to  return a single field of a row, you have to use `ExecuteScalar()`

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    string query = "SELECT TOP (1) [ZVNr] ZVNR_TABLE WHERE [ZVNr] = @zvnr order by [ZVNr] DESC";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zvnr", "20170530-01");
        connection.Open();
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers given above are ok but if you want just to see if it exist you can do a count instead

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    string query = "SELECT Count([ZVNr]) ZVNR_TABLE WHERE [ZVNr] = @zvnr order by [ZVNr] DESC";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zvnr", "20170530-01");
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to count here,  a  `null` check works aswell

Comment: A count insures that you will always return a int. Saves you the additional validation of checking if its null. Would make more logical sense too since you are checking if it exist you check for the occurrence.